# Data missing when inserting data from form to Mongo Collection from Iphone 5? (Meteor/Heroku)

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I've deployed my meteor app to heroku, which is survey app to get data from student from my school, when submitting survey form from computer or mobile other than Iphone 5 (probably some ios device also, haven't test yet) it works normal, but from Iphone 5, some data was missing, picture from MongoMlab:[image]

As the first one and last one submitting from computer and mobile which no missing data got from submmitting form survey, but the middle 2, missing some data, which is from 2 Iphone 5 of different version (Iphone 4s tested works normally).

My code just fairly short and simple, just a form with js event trigger to insert into mongo collection when user press submit, the collection to save survey data is inside /lib folder, js event is inside /client.
What is the problem that causes data to be missing when submitting form to mongo collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing data cause by safari, which i don't know what exactly causes the problem, but to get value from select filed or form, using jquery :

```
$('input[name="target"]').val()
```

solved my problem.